# How to compare value of property in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to use the if-directive in vue.js to determine which datafield should be shown in each table row:

```
<tr v-repeat="model">
    <td>@{{ title }}</td>
    <td>@{{ publish_date_start }}</td>
    <td v-if="model.publish = 1"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></td>
    <td v-if="model.publish = 0"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></td>
    <td class="data-list-action"><a href="/admin/news/@{{ id }}/edit" class="btn btn-warning">edit</a></td>
    <td class="data-list-action"><a href="#" v-on="click: deleteRequest(id)" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

If the value of the property 'publish' is 1, the datafield with the check has to be shown. If 0, it has to be the  a cross.

How can I compare 'model.publish' to a value?

UPDATE: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/8wy7w560/2/)

Comment: Would you mind providing your example in a jsfiddle (including your javascript code)?

Comment: @nils I added a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try with `v-if`:

```
<td v-if="publish"><span class="fa fa-check">Check</span></td>
<td v-if="!publish"><span class="fa fa-remove">Cross</span></td>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wy7w560/3/